# Upgrade of elastic search from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0.beata 1 and installing Kibana 4 beta version

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I installed kibana-4.0.0-BETA1.then realised that it needs elasticsearch-1.4.0.Beta1. So I upgraded elasticsearch 1.3.2 to newer version. kibana 4 is not working and i messed up my old elastic search and  kibana3 also.

**Problems with elasticsearch 1.3.2 and kibana 3**

1. I am able to create an index and that i can view in kibana but if I Darg Zoom , it is saying no indexes present in this time period. earlier it used to work fine.
2. unable to **save dashborad** on kibana
3. kibana-init in elastic search's health is red. So i deleted that index.

I installed new elk stack on other brand new machine.

**Problems with elasticsearch-1.4.0.Beta1 and kibana-4.0.0-BETA1**

1. most of the times kibana4 is not able to find elasticsearch
2. Unable to **SAVE** visualization. getting the following exception but visualization is saved

   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'byName' of undefined
       at BaseAggParam.FieldAggParamFactory.FieldAggParam.deserialize`
3. if I try to access any saved visualization, the same or above exception is showing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same here. I'm on ES 1.3.1, and most of the stuff in K4 works as far as I can tell. All except saving visualisation. And no, I did not upgrade to ES 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load Kibana 4, there's an ajax request to /config. It should return something like this:

```
apps: [{id:discover, name:Discover}, {id:visualize, name:Visualize}, {id:dashboard, name:Dashboard},…]
0: {id:discover, name:Discover}
1: {id:visualize, name:Visualize}
2: {id:dashboard, name:Dashboard}
3: {id:settings, name:Settings}
defaultAppId: "discover"
elasticsearch: "http://blah/elasticsearch"
kibanaIndex: "kibana-int"
port: 9200
```

You see the "kibanaIndex" in there? Make sure your Kibana 3 and Kibana 4 uses different index. Or they'll try load each other's data.

In Kibana 3 root, there's a config.js. Find the line: kibana_index: "kibana-int"

And maybe change that too. (one or the other.) Either way. Kibana saves its state and dashboard info in an index of its own. Make sure K3 and K4 have index different from each other.

Edit- btw, the error you are seeing is a bug. https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/1617 Seems like it's fixed.

Double Edit- This only applied back in K4 beta 1. I think I had to make other adjustments for beta 2. YMMV.

Comment: for me it didn't work well, changes: `port:5601, elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200"` if both kibana & elasticsearch are on same instance. I guess that the answer above works when the elasticsearch is on different instance and maybe need to add 9200 port.